# foreach() limited to 20 iterations in blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a foreach in blade that goes through an array with 25-30 or more elements and it always stops after 20.

I don't get any error, the script continues normally after that and I can't find any reason for it.

This is how it works: I upload a number of files (25-30 or more) and it doesn't take long (under a minute to return the view). I get the files information, perform a database query and send the array to the view.

```
return view('checkfiles')->with('files', $files);
```

In the view I have:

```
@foreach ($files as $file)
    <div class="block">
        <input type="text" name="data[{{ $file->count }}][packagename]" value="{{ $file->packagename }}">
     ...
    </div>
@endforeach
```

And no matter how many files or what files I upload, I only get this displayed 20 times.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that you're not paginating your query results?

Comment: do a `dd(count($files));` at your controller to check files count

Comment: I've already done that and fixed the problem too. It was limited in php.ini :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've thankfully managed to find the answer quickly. php.ini was limited to 20 file uploads.